# Perguntas sem retorno da parte de quem perguntou

Tags: debate

Não é uma pergunta, é mais uma sugestão que gostaria de colocar em discussão.

Neste site existe e bem, uma grande preocupação com a qualidade. Eu acho que o primeiro fator de qualidade de qualquer código é esse código conseguir resolver um problema.

A maior parte da questões que são colocadas são problemas específicos que gentilmente todos aqui procuram ajudar a resolver, mas a maior parte das vezes não sabemos se a situação ficou resolvida, porque quem colocou a questão não tem o respeito de responder e marcar qual a solução que resolveu o problema.

Este fato também é ruim , porque mais tarde quando chegamos a essa questão para resolvermos um problema idêntico , não sabemos qual solução usar. Nessa situação temos duas opções: ou fazemos uma pergunta duplicada e ficamos esperando novas respostas ou temos que testar todas as soluções sem ter a certeza que alguma está certa.

Eu saio da página e vou procurar noutro lugar.

Por isso a minha sugestão, enquanto a pessoa que fez a pergunta não der retorno numa pergunta em aberto, não pode fazer mais perguntas.

Poderia também existir uma forma que marcar a resposta: "Não resolve o problema".

Isto é o rascunho de uma ideia que coloquei em discussão. Penso que este é uma aspetos mais frágeis deste site e que todos os  utilizadores poderiam tentar resolver.

Este site com a validação por teste em situação real de todas as perguntas, era a wikipédia do código. Milhões de situações testadas e confirmadas que funcionam.

Comment: Nem sempre uma pergunta é respondida rapidamente, e enquanto ela está aberta o usuário não pode ser impedido de continuar perguntando.

Comment: Antigamente existia o *accept-rate* (taxa de aceitação [de respostas]) que ajudava a, ahem, "incentivar" os usuários a aceitarem mais respostas. Entretanto, o mesmo [foi removido](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/177950) por se pensar que o benefício não justificava o desgaste entre os usuários. Pessoalmente, fiquei triste por isso, pois ajudava muito a identificar os ["vampiros de ajuda"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/215). Entretanto a maioria das pessoas preferia antagonizá-los do que orientá-los, de modo que no fim eu achei acertada a decisão de não mostrar mais essa taxa.

Answer (score 6):

Estava indo muito bem até `[...]não pode fazer mais perguntas`. Acho que é o mesmo caso de não se obrigar justificativa no downvote.

Quanto à sinalização de "Não resolve o problema", basta dar o feedback no comentário da resposta explicando o motivo. É assim que funciona e bem por sinal, sempre vejo respostas sendo atualizadas após os comentário.

O resto concordo 10000%. As vezes você se empenha em responder uma questão e o AP some e depois aparece com uma nova pergunta. Quando isso ocorre eu costumo comentar avisando para aceitar a provável questão que resolve o problema - link de ajuda também auxilia usuários novos.

As vezes uma pergunta não fornece uma solução, e precisa não ter uma resposta marcada para proporcionar outras melhores.

O pior caso seria o AP precisar fazer multiplas perguntas sumultaneas e ser impossibilitado por não ter aceitado nenhuma resposta anterior. Isso seria inviável.